# Proper way to determine a CI/CD pipeline for vagrant using gitlab-runner with virtualbox executor?

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox, gitlab-ci, ubuntu-18.04

I'm bit stuck lately, because i've started to learn about CI/CD with Gitlab. I'm interested in developing a pipeline for my vagrant development with virtualbox. I'm new to Gitlab CE, but I see there is a virtualbox executor. What would be the proper way to test a vagrant automation? Find below my developement environment:

1. Local Vagrant Virtualzation running Virtualbox with a private network (Host-Machine: Windows 10 Laptop)
2. Self-hosted Gitlab CE instance (Host-Machine: Ubuntu Server connected to LAN)
3. Gitlab-Runner running as a docker-service on the same machine as the Gitlab CE

My questions:

1. Is it possible for the gitlab-runner to connect to my local vagrant machine using Virtualbox Executor?
2. Any experiences/references i can read how to develop a CI/CD Pipeline for Vagrant?
3. Should I have a clone of Vagrant/Virtualbox on my Ubuntu Server in order to get this running?

Much love for your help